# How to set work item state / reason when using Pending Changes window

Tags: tfs, workflow, workitem

I am using a custom workflow for tasks in TFS 2010.  However, when I check in code using the Pending Changes window and "Resolve" a task it is automatically put into a state of Closed with a reason of Cut.

Is there any way to modify this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action that is defaulted to in Visual Studio when you associate a check-in to a work item is controlled by the Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.Checkin action in your process template.  See http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/000230.html

Comment: Actually I had seen your blog post about this and removed the action.